# Pagination of table contains table

Tags: javascript, jsp, pagination

i want to do the pagination of table that contains an another table,
i try this script function in my JSP page,
but it work to table that not cotains an another table
this is the function:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
function Pager(tableName, itemsPerPage) { 
    this.tableName = tableName; 
    this.itemsPerPage = itemsPerPage; 
    this.currentPage = 1; 
    this.pages = 0; 
    this.inited = false; 

    this.showRecords = function(from, to) {         
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows; 
        // i starts from 1 to skip table header row 
        for (var i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) { 
            if (i < from || i > to)   
                rows[i].style.display = 'none'; 
            else 
                rows[i].style.display = ''; 
        } 
    } 

    this.showPage = function(pageNumber) { 
     if (! this.inited) { 
      alert("not inited"); 
      return; 
     } 

        var oldPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage); 
        oldPageAnchor.className = 'pg-normal'; 

        this.currentPage = pageNumber; 
        var newPageAnchor = document.getElementById('pg'+this.currentPage); 
        newPageAnchor.className = 'pg-selected'; 

        var from = (pageNumber - 1) * itemsPerPage + 1; 
        var to = from + itemsPerPage - 1; 
        this.showRecords(from, to); 
    }    

    this.prev = function() { 
        if (this.currentPage > 1) 
            this.showPage(this.currentPage - 1); 
    } 

    this.next = function() { 
        if (this.currentPage < this.pages) { 
            this.showPage(this.currentPage + 1); 
        } 
    }                         

    this.init = function() { 
        var rows = document.getElementById(tableName).rows; 
        var records = (rows.length - 1);  
        this.pages = Math.ceil(records / itemsPerPage); 
        this.inited = true; 
    } 

    this.showPageNav = function(pagerName, positionId) { 
     if (! this.inited) { 
      alert("not inited"); 
      return; 
     } 
     var element = document.getElementById(positionId); 

     var pagerHtml = '<span onclick="' + pagerName + '.prev();" class="pg-normal"> « Prev </span> | '; 
        for (var page = 1; page <= this.pages; page++)  
            pagerHtml += '<span id="pg' + page + '" class="pg-normal" onclick="' + pagerName + '.showPage(' + page + ');">' + page + '</span> | '; 
        pagerHtml += '<span onclick="'+pagerName+'.next();" class="pg-normal"> Next »</span>';             

        element.innerHTML = pagerHtml; 
    } 
} 
</script> 


    <div id="pageNavPosition"></div> 

<script type="text/javascript"><!-- 
        var pager = new Pager('re', 2);  
        pager.init();  
        pager.showPageNav('pager', 'pageNavPosition');  
        pager.showPage(1); 
    //--></script>
```

and this is the table code:

```
   <table  cellpadding="6"  width="100%">
        <thead  >
            <tr bgcolor="#FC6C85">
                <th  align="center"><img src="Logo.png" width="600" height="70" alt="Logo"/>
                </th>
        </thead>

    </table>
    <h1>Message Details</h1>
    <table cellspacing='2'><tr><th align='center'> <form action="Controlleur?action=msgSum">
            <a href="Controlleur?action=msgSum">Messages Summary</a></form></th><th align='center'>  <form form action="Controlleur?action=sendmsg">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="sendmsg"  />
        <a href="Controlleur?action=sendmsg">Send Messages</a></th></tr></table>



    </form>
    <table  cellspacing="1" width=60% >

        <tbody> <%for (int i = 0; i < msgController.getAllMessages().size(); i++) {%>
            <% if ((Integer) (msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author()) == (Integer.parseInt((String) session.getAttribute("usrid")))) {%>
            <tr bgcolor="#FC6C85">
                <% String autname=msgController.getAuthorName(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author());%>
                <td width=20% ><form action="Controlleur?action=author"> <input type="hidden" name="action" value="author"  />
                        <input type="hidden" name="author" value=""/>
                        <a href="Controlleur?action=author&author=<%=autname%>"><%=autname%></a>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td><table><tr><td width=20%><%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle()%></td>
                            <td width=20%><form action="Controlleur?action=editMessage">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="editMessage"  />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="titrem" value="<%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle()%>"  />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="subjm" value="<%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject()%>"  />

                                    <input type="hidden" name="mgid" value="<%=msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())%>"  />

                                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="editMessage" /></form></td>
                            <td width=20%><form action="Controlleur?action=deleteMessage">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteMessage"  />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="mgidd" value="<%=msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())%>"  />
                                    <input type="submit" value="Delete" name="deleteMessage" /></form></td>
                        </tr></table></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td colspan="3"   width=30% height=10><%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject()%></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td colspan="3" width=30%><font color="#CB2C71"><%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDates()%></font></td></tr>


            <tr> <td></td><td><table id='re' ><thead><tr><th colspan="3">Comments</th>
                <th>Date</th></tr></thead><%for (int h = 0; h < cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).size(); h++) {%>

        <tr><td bgcolor="#FC6C85"><form action="Controlleur?action=author"> 


                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="author"  />
                    <%String authorName = cmt.getAuthorName(cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getId_pers());
                   int commentId=cmt.getId(cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getDate());
                    int idPers=cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getId_pers();
                    int idAuthor=Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("usrid"));
                    %>
                       <input type="submit" value="<%=authorName%>" name="author" />
                   </form></td><td><%=cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getSubject()%>
                   </td><td></td><td><%=cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getDates()%></td><td>

                   </td><%if(idPers==idAuthor){%>
                   <td><form action="Controlleur?action=deleteComment">
                           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteComment"/>
                           <input type="hidden" name="cmtID" value="<%=commentId%>"/>
                           <a href="Controlleur?action=deleteComment&cmtID=<%=commentId%>">delete</a>
                       </form></td>
                       <td><form action="Controlleur?action=updateComment">
                           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateComment"/>
                           <input type="hidden" name="cmtID" value="<%=commentId%>"/>
                           <a href="Controlleur?action=updateComment&cmtID=<%=commentId%>">Edit</a></form></td>

                       <%}%>

        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FC6C85"></tr><%}%>
                        <tr><form action="Controlleur?action=addcomment"><td></td><td colspan="2">
                                <textarea  name="commentSubject" value="" rows="1" cols="38"  ></textArea></td>
```

"  />

<%} else {%>
 
        <% String autname=msgController.getAuthorName(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author());%>
                     
                            
                            "><%=autname%>
                        
                    
        <%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle()%> 
    <%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject()%>
    <%=msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDates()%>

Comments
                    Date<%for (int h = 0; h < cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).size(); h++) {%>

```
        <tr><td bgcolor="#FC6C85"><form action="Controlleur?action=author"> 


                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="author"  />
                    <%String authorName = cmt.getAuthorName(cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getId_pers());
                   int commentId=cmt.getId(cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getDate());
                    int idPers=cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getId_pers();
                    int idAuthor=Integer.parseInt((String)session.getAttribute("usrid"));
                    %>
                       <input type="submit" value="<%=authorName%>" name="author" />
                   </form></td><td><%=cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getSubject()%>
                   </td><td></td><td><%=cmt.getAllComments(msgController.getMessageID(msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getId_Author(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getTitle(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getSubject(), msgController.getAllMessages().get(i).getDate())).get(h).getDates()%></td><td>

                   </td><%if(idPers==idAuthor){%>
                   <td><form action="Controlleur?action=deleteComment">
                           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="deleteComment"/>
                           <input type="hidden" name="cmtID" value="<%=commentId%>"/>
                           <a href="Controlleur?action=deleteComment&cmtID=<%=commentId%>">delete</a>
                       </form></td>
                       <td><form action="Controlleur?action=updateComment">
                           <input type="hidden" name="action" value="updateComment"/>
                           <input type="hidden" name="cmtID" value="<%=commentId%>"/>
                           <a href="Controlleur?action=updateComment&cmtID=<%=commentId%>">Edit</a></form></td>

                       <%}%>

        </tr>
        <tr bgcolor="#FC6C85"></tr><%}%>
                        <tr><form action="Controlleur?action=addcomment"><td></td><td colspan="2">
                        <textarea  name="commentSubject" value="" rows="1" cols="38"  ></textArea></td>
```

"  />

<%}
    }%>

```
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

can you help me please

Comment: Please post the code of the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't include the table here, I assume that the 're' passed into the Pager function is the name of the outer table. If that's the case, name the inner table and pass that name to your pager.

That's the best I can offer without actually seeing all of the code. I hope it helps.